# Same session and session ID for different subdomains in Grails project - How can I do that?

Tags: session, grails, subdomain

I am currently working on a project that supports multiple languages. In order to be seo friendly, I am trying to redirect users subdomains corresponding to their locale (or their preferred language).

I.e., my projects's url is *mydomain.com* and I work with the subdomains *en.mydomain.com*, *es.mydomain.com*, *de.mydomain.com*, *fr.mydomain.com* ... you get the idea. All subdomains are served by the same grails app for now.

What happens is that my grails project maintains different sessions (as seen by the session ids) for every single subdomain, hence information is lost, when a user switches between languages. I had not forseen that. :(

How can I explicitly set the session identifier? I would like it to be based on just *mydomain.com*.

I got the hint that Apache Tomcat offers something like

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain=".mydomain.com">
```

, but that does not help for the devel environment etc.

Any hints? Have you tried storing session information in the DB? This is sometimes used for load-balancing purposes and might help here as well?!

Help is highly appreciated (as always)! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can share sessions between different context roots let alone sub-domains. 
For load balancing most configs use sticky sessions where the same session requests are  directed to the same app server. There are configs to replicate sessions across the cluster under the load balancer to enable switching servers for subsequent request.

You have several options here:

1. Ask a question specific to apache URL rewrite rules if they can preserve http session across a url rewrite.
2. forgo the subdomain approach and use their browser locale to sniff out what message bundles to use. (i like this approach)
3. (used to be 2:) ) explore putting session info in the cookies that is readable across domain. i know cross domain cookies r not allowed, but subdomain should be ok.

Comment: Actually option 2 is what I want to explore. That is why I suggested _sessionCookieDomain_ as a possible solution. However, I have no idea, how I can do that for grails devel (not running in tomcat)?!

Comment: cookies are fairly simple, you don't need apache or whatnot rules. Browser handles cookie handling, and JavaScript can manipulate your cookies on the client side. On the server side you got your tags: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Tags/cookie.html , there is even a cookie plugin :) .             you can use: 
request.cookies.each { println "${it.name} == ${it.value} } ------ and set ----
def c = new Cookie(someName, someValue)
c.maxAge = someNumberInSeconds
response.addCookie(c)

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving it, is using an nginx as an reverse proxy in front of your tomcat and translate requests from `fr.mydomain.com` to `localhost/yourapplication/fr/` or something.

He will care about your cookies. I have appended an example configuration (slightly shortened), which I have used once:

```
server {
    server_name  fr.yourdomain.com;
    location /office {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080/yourapplication/fr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

server {
   server_name  es.yourdomain.com;
    location /office {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080/yourapplication/es;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
[..]
```